# Replace a string in shell script by a string with special character

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I am trying to replace a string inside a shell script by a string with special character:

```
name="test&commit"
echo "{{name}}" | sed "s/{{name}}/$name/g"
```

and the result I am getting is

```
test{{name}}commit
```

I know that adding \ before & will make it work but the name param is given by the user so I'd like my code to somoehow predict that. Do anybody knows how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use another sed command to add a backslash before all the special characters in the given input string.

```
$ name="test&commit"
$ name1=$(sed 's/[^[:alpha:][:digit:][:blank:]]/\\&/g' <<<"$name")
$ echo $name1
test\&commit
$ echo "{{name}}" | sed "s/{{name}}/$name1/g"
test&commit
```

It would be minimized as,

```
$ name="test&commit"
$ echo "{{name}}" | sed "s/{{name}}/$(sed 's/[^[:alpha:][:digit:][:blank:]]/\\&/g' <<<"$name")/g"
test&commit
```

Comment: Does this `name1=$(sed 's/[[:punct:]]/\\&/g' <<<"$name")` also suit ? We could add maybe the `[:cntrl:]` also for special character if allowed.

Comment: `cntrl` class is to add to `punct`, not replace :-)

Comment: All you actually need is `sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g'`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29626460/1745001.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly change way of providing the template and values:

```
$ cat template

   Dear {{name}}
    I hope to see you {{day}}.
```

(template is a file with `{{var}}`, to be instantiated with values)

```
$ name='Mary&Susan' day=tomorrow    perl -pe 's/{{(\w+)}}/$ENV{$1}/g' template

   Dear Mary&Susan,
    I hope to see you tomorrow.
```

Answer (score 0):

In perl you can turn off expressions with \Q \P.
I fill the vars template, placeholder and name:

```
$ echo "template=$template"
template=The name is {{name}} and we like that.
$ echo "placeholder=$placeholder"
placeholder={{name}}
$ echo "name=$name"
name=test&commit
```

The replacement will be performed with

```
$ echo $template | perl -pe 's/\Q'$placeholder'\E/'$name'/g'
The name is test&commit and we like that.
```